# Why the "y" prop cannot be set in layer_smooths in ggvis?

Tags: r, ggvis

This works fine:

```
mtcars %>% ggvis(x = ~wt) %>% layer_lines(y = ~mpg)
```

But this:

```
mtcars %>% ggvis(x = ~wt) %>% layer_smooths(y = ~mpg)
```

gives an error: "Error: Can't find prop y.update."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
mtcars %>% ggvis(x = ~wt, y = ~mpg) %>% layer_smooths()
```